# Ifplugd: Error "Incorrect action argument"

Tags: bash, shell, networking, network-interface

I have an error in the ifplugd.
Whenever a new ethernet cable is plugged into my appliance, then ifplugd should ping the Gateway.
This is what the script looks like:

ping.sh

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "in ifplugd" >> /tmp/ifplugd.txt
if [ "$2" == "up" ]; then
   logger IfPlugD executes script
   echo "Pinging 10.10.10.1 5 times"
   echo "Executing State $2 ifdown ifup on :: $1 :: $(date)" >> /var/ifplugdlog.txt
   ping 10.10.10.1 -c 5;
fi
```

Sadly, it $2 variable returns nothing.
I tried to check, why it returns nothing, so I ran the ifplugd.action script, which is runs automatically everytime a state changes. It looks like the following:

ifplugd.action

```sh
#!/bin/sh

set -e
case "$2" in
up)
   run-parts --arg="$1" --arg="$2" /etc/ifplugd/action.d/
   ;;
down)
   run-parts --reverse --arg="$1" --arg="$2" /etc/ifplugd/action.d/
*)
   echo "ifplugd.action: Incorrect action argument" >&2
   exit 1
   ;;
esac
```

It runs with the following arguments in the `/etc/default/ifplugd`-file

ifplugd

```
INTERFACES="enp2s0 enp3s0 enp6s0"
HOTPLUG_INTERFACES="enp2s0 enp3s0 enp6s0"
ARGS="-q -f -d10 -w -I"
SUSPEND_ACTION="stop"
```

And when I remove the network cable and attach it again, it still gives me no response, since my the if clause is getting ignored in my ping.sh, because the $2 variable is null.

Can someone help me, why I get the error "ifplugd: Incorrect action arguments" and how to fix it?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Package seems to be out of date - used another package and made a cron

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).